# Reverse in descending order

Tags: java

For the given set of characters by user, choose integers only and sort them in descending order and put in their position leaving other characters position intact.

So if the user enters the string and symbols the position of string and symbol should remain in same position and only the integer should be in descending order and I am only being able in maintaining in descending order.

Sample input

2,a,5,3,#,11,e

output 11,a,5,3,#,2,e

```
public class sort {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num, i, j, temp;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the number of character to be sort:");
    num = input.nextInt();

    int array[] = new int[num];
    System.out.println("Enter " + num + " character ");

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        array[i] = input.nextInt();
    }

    for (i = 0; i < (num - 1); i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < num - i - 1; j++) {
            if (array[j] < array[j + 1]) {
                temp = array[j];
                array[j] = array[j + 1];
                array[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Sorted list of integers:");

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        System.out.println(array[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For You to be able to take symbols and integers as input,you should scan strings,not integers. Then convert the sting to integer by using Integer.parseInt(s), where s is a string.